# Crear un sub dominio que apunte a un sub dominio de otro dominio

Tags: nginx, dns

Tengo un dominio (dominiopropio.com) y necesito poner un sub dominio (observatorio.dominiopropio.com). El detalle es que el sub dominio debe de apuntar o cargar el contenido de otro sub dominio de un dominio diferente (contenido.otrodominio.com).

Como puedo realizar eso?
El sitio web de dominiopropio.com esta eb un servidor nginx.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es un proxy_pass. Y deberias separar dos bloques de server para el dominio y para el subdominio.
Ejemplo:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name dominiopropio.com;

  #haz lo que quieras aqui;

}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name observatorio.dominiopropio.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://contenido.otrodominio.com$request_uri;
  }

}
```

Pero observatorio.dominiopropio.com debe estar configurado en tu otrodominio.com para ser recibido. Si lo que quieres es que cuando entre al subdominio, simplemente haz un 301 en vez de proxy_pass.